# Cannot start TestContainers in Docker Desktop 4.24.2 on Macbook M1

Tags: spring-boot, docker-desktop, testcontainers

I have created a simple project and am able to start the test container on Rancher Desktop.
However, When I ran it with Docker Desktop, I got an issue with HTTP_PROXY_AUTH (407) while trying to pull the Ryuk image.

What is the root cause of this issue and how to fix it?

Please find the error below:

````
tests-1  | java.io.UncheckedIOException: Error while executing Request{method=POST, path=/v1.30/images/create?fromImage=testcontainers%2Fryuk%3A0.3.1, body=null, bodyBytes=null, hijackedInput=null, headers={accept=application/octet-stream, content-type=application/json}}
tests-1  |  at org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.okhttp.OkDockerHttpClient.execute(OkDockerHttpClient.java:233) ~[testcontainers-1.15.3.jar:na]
tests-1  |  at org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.DefaultInvocationBuilder.execute(DefaultInvocationBuilder.java:228) ~[testcontainers-1.15.3.jar:na]
tests-1  |  at org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.DefaultInvocationBuilder.lambda$executeAndStream$1(DefaultInvocationBuilder.java:269) ~[testcontainers-1.15.3.jar:na]
tests-1  |  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
tests-1  | Caused by: java.net.ProtocolException: Received HTTP_PROXY_AUTH (407) code while not using proxy```
````